# Context Menu issue

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub lstrecentdocs_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstrecentdocs.SelectedIndexChanged

    If lstrecentdocs.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        lstrecentdocs.ContextMenuStrip = Nothing
    Else
        lstrecentdocs.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip2
    End If
End Sub
```

In ListBox Some Blank Space is there ......while selecting items in ListBox it displays Contex menu Properly but  if item selected item and   click anywhere in ListBox it showing contex Menu...........

My requirement is while selecting the items it shows contexmenu in proper place only where the item selected.

Thank in advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private Sub lstrecentdocs_MouseUp_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lstrecentdocs.MouseUp

```
    Try
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
            Dim index = lstrecentdocs.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)
            If index >= 0 Then
                lstrecentdocs.SelectedIndex = index
                ContextMenuStrip2.Show(lstrecentdocs, e.Location)
            Else
                ContextMenuStrip2.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try       
End Sub
```